# How do I run a list of powershell commands in php?

Tags: php, powershell

I need to run a list of powershell commands from php. I can't load it from file it needs to be a php string. The string also has the script `./Merge-PowerPointPresentation -Source $Presentations -Verbose -Open;` which is powershell script in the current directory. This script combines a two or more power point presentations and opens it. Here is my code but it isn't working.

```
$script = 'powershell.exe Move-Item -Path "C:\Users\private\Documents\Test1.pptx" -Destination "C:\xampp\htdocs\test"
Move-Item -Path "C:\Users\private\Documents\Test2.pptx" -Destination "C:\xampp\htdocs\test"
$presentation = "./Test1.pptx","./Test2.pptx";
./Merge-PowerPointPresentation -Source $Presentations -Verbose -Open;
Move-Item -Path "C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Test1.pptx" -Destination "C:\Users\private\Documents"
Move-Item -Path "C:\xampp\htdocs\test\Test2.pptx" -Destination "C:\Users\private\Documents"';
shell_exec($script);
echo "Done";
```

I have run the script in that code as powershell file and it works.
The expected result is I will be able to open the combined powerpoints.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Do you have error reporting turned on? Also, unless you are constructing the script in PHP before execution, put it in a file then make it executable and run it from PHP. Even if you are constructing it in PHP, you could write it to disk, then execute it,

Comment: Have you tried using `exec()`? It returns any output from your script as an array, and also can indicate if an error occurred. Remember that the script will be executed by the web user's account. Make sure that user can execute the commands in the script.

Comment: Is `$presentation = "./Test1.pptx","./Test2.pptx";` a proper shell command? I'm not familiar with much of the shell commands. Also, is $Presentations set somewhere else in the script? Or is it supposed to be `$presentation`? If you are expecting PHP to substitute these, it will only do that if the string is enclosed with double quotes.

Comment: Yes presentation is a proper shell command. I put the whole script in ps1 file and ran it and it worked.